# How to set different heights in two select2 elements in the same web page?

Tags: css

I'm new in using select2 plugin and I need some help concerning how to set 2 different heights of 2 select2 elements in the same page. I saw the code for setting a height in all select2 elements in the same page. here it is:

```
.select2 - container . select2 - choice, .select2 - result - label
{
height:26px;
}
```

If I use this code, all the select2 elements in the page have the same height (I mean 26px). My question is how do I have to do so that they have different heights in the same page.

Comment: Could you give us the HTML for the select2 elements?

Answer (score 0):

put each one inside a different div and give that div a unique id and style according to it:

```
#div1 .select2 - container . select2 - choice,#div1 .select2 - result - label
    {
    height:26px;
    }

#div2 .select2 - container . select2 - choice,#div2 .select2 - result - label
    {
    height:36px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for these codes. Everything works perfectly! However,  I  added to these code a  new background but the arrow button doesn't change. Is there another code for that?

Comment: any change you want to make, just copy the container div name and place it before the css selector.

PS: Please dont forget to accept my answer.

Comment: Osmancode, i have another problem. when a select an item, it aligns in the center when i use internet explorer. I want to align items selected on the right side. Is this possible?